# Yet another hash tuple in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, hashcode

Is there something terribly wrong with this implementation?

```
template <class T>
constexpr inline std::size_t hash_combine(T const& v,
  std::size_t const seed = {}) noexcept
{
  return seed ^ (std::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2));
}

template <typename T> struct hash;

template <typename ...T>
struct hash<std::tuple<T...>>
{
  template <typename A1, typename ...A, std::size_t ...I>
  static auto apply_tuple(std::tuple<A1, A...> const& t,
    std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
  {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(A))
    {
      return hash_combine(std::get<0>(t),
        hash<std::tuple<A const&...>>()({std::get<I + 1>(t)...})
      );
    }
    else
    {
      return std::hash<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<A1>>>()(
        std::get<0>(t));
    }
  }

  auto operator()(std::tuple<T...> const& t) const noexcept
  {
    return apply_tuple(t,
      std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T) - 1>()
    );
  }
};
```

EDIT: This is better, I think:

```
template <typename ...T>
struct hash<std::tuple<T...>>
{
  template <std::size_t ...I>
  static auto apply_tuple(std::tuple<T...> const& t,
    std::index_sequence<I...>)
  {
    std::size_t seed{};

    return ((seed = hash_combine(std::get<I>(t), seed)), ...);
  }

  auto operator()(std::tuple<T...> const& t) const
  {
    return apply_tuple(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>());
  }
};
```

Comment: Care about editing code in your question.  Otherwise, I didn't notice something wrong in your code.

Comment: great, maybe you'll think of something later.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't handle empty tuples gracefully.  The first version generates a compilation error, and the second version returns `void`.  For the first version, you can add an `apply_tuple` overload for empty tuples.  For the second version, you can change

```
return ((seed = hash_combine(std::get<I>(t), seed)), ...);
```

to

```
((seed = hash_combine(std::get<I>(t), seed)), ...);
return seed;
```

---

Is `0` really a good initial seed?  Some prime number, I guess, might be better (e.g., `672807365`, [which is what MSVC returns for `std::hash<std::nullptr_t>{}(nullptr)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54147254/9716597)).

---

The tuple unpacking can be simplified with `std::apply`, avoiding `index_sequence`s:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct hash<std::tuple<Args...>> {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple) const noexcept
    {
        return std::apply([](const auto&... args) {
            auto seed = static_cast<std::size_t>(672807365);
            ((seed = hash_combine(args, seed)), ...);
            return seed;
        }, tuple);
    }
};
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jieey9yon25o6Tsc))

Comment: very nice, one of these days, we are going to hack it down to a one-liner.

Comment: @user1095108 Yeah, with [P1858](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1858r1.html) it's gonna become `((seed = hash_combine(tuple.[:], seed)), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

It should have been like this all along:

```
template <typename> struct hash;

template <std::size_t SEED = 672807365, typename ...T>
constexpr auto hash_combine(T&& ...v)
{
  auto seed{SEED};

  (
    (
      seed ^= hash<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>()(std::forward<T>(v)) +
        0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2)
    ),
    ...
  );

  return seed;
}

template <typename ...T>
struct hash<std::tuple<T...>>
{
  constexpr auto operator()(std::tuple<T...> const& t) const
  {
    return std::apply(hash_combine, t);
  }
};
```